# Creating new cleveref types

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

The package `cleveref` has two types of references, `\cref` for lowercase and `\Cref` for uppercase. Does the package provide a way to define more types? If not, how may you define one yourself?

As an example, one may want to define abbreviated versions of the references, such that the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, amsthm, hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% Defining \abbrcref
% Defining \abbrCref
% Defining \abbrcrefformat
% Defining \abbrCrefformat

\crefformat{theorem}{#2theorem #1#3}
\Crefformat{theorem}{#2Theorem #1#3}
\abbrcrefformat{theorem}{#2th.#1#3}
\abbrCrefformat{theorem}{#2Th.#1#3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        \label{sometheorem}
    \end{theorem}

    \cref{sometheorem}, \Cref{sometheorem}, \abbrcref{sometheorem}, \abbrCref{sometheorem}
\end{document}
```

Would produce:

[image]

How would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a variable reference name and introduce a conditional for the cross references you may want to abbreviate.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, amsthm, hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% Defining \abbrcref
% Defining \abbrCref
% Defining \abbrcrefformat
% Defining \abbrCrefformat

\newcommand{\theoremref}{\ifabbrcref th.\,\else theorem~\fi}
\newcommand{\Theoremref}{\ifabbrcref Th.\,\else Theorem~\fi}

\crefformat{theorem}{#2\theoremref#1#3}
\Crefformat{theorem}{#2\Theoremref#1#3}

\newif\ifabbrcref
\NewDocumentCommand{\genericabbrcref}{msom}{%
  \begingroup\abbrcreftrue
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{#1*{#4}}{#1*[#3]{#4}}%
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{#1{#4}}{#1[#3]{#4}}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\abbrcref}{\genericabbrcref\cref}
\newcommand{\abbrCref}{\genericabbrcref\Cref}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{sometheorem}
\end{theorem}

\cref{sometheorem}, \Cref{sometheorem}, \abbrcref{sometheorem}, \abbrCref{sometheorem}

\end{document}
```

See `texdoc xparse` for more information about `\NewDocumentCommand`.

[image]