# Use two comma lists to build a test function using \str_case:nn

Tags: macros, expl3

Suppose given two comma lists of the same length:

```
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_clist { key1, key2, key3 }
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_acts_clist { act1, act2, act3 }
```

How can one convert them into a test function of the following form?

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \TestFunction } { m }
  {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { key1 } { act1 }
        { key2 } { act2 }
        { key3 } { act3 }
      } { No ~ action! }
  }
```

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l__mymodule_keys_clist
\clist_new:N \l__mymodule_acts_clist

\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_clist { key1, key2, key3 }
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_acts_clist { act1, act2, act3 }

\NewDocumentCommand { \TestFunction } { m }
  {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { key1 } { act1 }
        { key2 } { act2 }
        { key3 } { act3 }
      } { No ~ action! }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\TestFunction{key2}

\TestFunction{key4}

\end{document}
```

The expected result would be

[image]

The MWE produces this result but the content of the `\TestFunction` is hard-coded and is not dynamically created from the two given comma lists.

---

Below is my current attempt:

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \TestFunction } { m }
  {
    \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l__mymodule_acts_clist
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_clist
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { { ##1 } }
        \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpb_tl
        \exp_args:NNe \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { { \l_tmpb_tl } }
      }
    \exp_args:Nno \str_case:nnF { #1 } { \l_tmpa_tl } { No ~ action! }
  }
```

Though it works in this particular case, the problem is that it uses the `e`-type expansion which would require the content of the second comma list to be fully expandable, which is not the case if it contains things like `\textbf`. The thing is that when popping the first item from the second `clist`, it seems that I can only save it to a macro, say `\l_tmpb_tl`; then later on, when I wish to append `{ \l_tmpb_tl }` to a temporary macro (here `\l_tmpa_tl`), the `o`-type expansion that expand it once does not seem to be enough. Is there some way to improve this code or is there an alternative and better approach?

Comment: Please tell us what the results of `\TestFunction{key2}` and `\TestFunction{key4}` should be.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the comment. I have added the expected result along with some explanation.

Comment: What would be the purpose of all this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to turn the two comma lists into a property list (I'm rather keen to believe this is an XY-question).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makepropfromclists}{O{default}mm}
 {% #1 = name of the prop, #2 = name of the keys clist, #3 = name of the actions clist
  \prop_clear_new:c { l_mymodule_keysacts_#1_prop }
  \int_step_inline:nn { \clist_count:c { l__mymodule_#2_clist } }
   {
    \prop_put:cxx { l_mymodule_keysacts_#1_prop }
     { \clist_item:cn { l__mymodule_#2_clist } { ##1 } }
     { \clist_item:cn { l__mymodule_#3_clist } { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\TestFunction}{O{default}m}
 {
  \prop_if_in:cnTF { l_mymodule_keysacts_#1_prop } { #2 }
   {
    \prop_get:cnN { l_mymodule_keysacts_#1_prop } { #2 } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   { No~action! }
 }

\clist_new:N \l__mymodule_keys_clist
\clist_new:N \l__mymodule_acts_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_clist { key1, key2, key3 }
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_acts_clist { act1, act2, act3 }

\makepropfromclists{keys}{acts}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TestFunction{key2}

\TestFunction{key4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use clists for what they aren't thought for.

Comment: Actually, inspired by your [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579146/194994), I was thinking of adding German support for my package [crefthe](https://ctan.org/pkg/crefthe). Currently I stored, in order, the name of declensions, definite articles and names in singular and plural forms into different `clist`s (for now I am not really sure what would be the difference with using `seq`), and were expected to use `\str_case` to show the corresponding string for the given declension type. That was the motivation for this question.

Comment: By the way, please allow me to ask a follow up question. I noticed that you used `\prop_put:cxx` with `x`-type expansion, but it seems OK for those to `clist`s to contain things like `\textbf`. However, in my attempt given at the end of my question, even if I write `\exp_args:NNx`, the appearance of `\textbf` still causes errors. What is going on here?

Comment: @Jinwen There's no problem, because `\clist_item:Nn` (or variants thereof) returns the item protected by `\exp_not:n`.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement your task directly using TeX primitives, no expl3 is needed:

```
\def\keys {key1,key2,key3}
\def\acts {act1,act2,act3}

\def\actsX #1,#2\end#3{\expandafter\def\csname k:#3\endcsname{#1}\def\acts{#2}} 
\def\setkeys #1,{\ifx\end#1\else
   \expandafter\actsX \acts,\end {#1}%
   \expandafter\setkeys \fi
}
\expandafter\setkeys\keys,\end,

\def\TestFunction#1{%
   \ifcsname k:#1\endcsname 
      \csname k:#1\endcsname
   \else 
      No action%
   \fi
}

\TestFunction{key2}  % prints: act2

\TestFunction{key4}  % prints: No action
```

The `\setkeys` macro with the parameter `key1,key2,key3,\end,` defines macros `\k:key1` with value `act1`, `\k:key2` with value `act2` etc. If there is more keys than actions then the macros with trailing keys are empty. Finally, the macro `\TestFunction` prints the value of given key or prints `No action` if the macro isn't defined.

Answer (score 3):

Using `\seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN` gets us most of the way there:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Starting clists
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_clist { key1, key2, key3 }
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_acts_clist { act1, act2, act3 }

% Convert to sequences
\seq_set_from_clist:NN \l__mymodule_keys_seq \l__mymodule_keys_clist
\seq_set_from_clist:NN \l__mymodule_acts_seq \l__mymodule_acts_clist

% The value that we're searching for
\tl_new:N \l__mymodule_search_tl

% The mapping function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mymodule_map:nn {
    \tl_if_eq:NnT \l__mymodule_search_tl { #1 } {
        % \seq_map_break:n { #2 \use_none:n } % Doesn't work for some reason
        \prg_break:n { #2 \use_none:n }
    }
}

% The fallthrough action
\tl_const:Nn \c__mymodule_fallthrough_tl { No ~ action! }

% The user-accessible function
\NewDocumentCommand { \TestFunction } { m } {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__mymodule_search_tl { #1 }
    \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN
        \l__mymodule_keys_seq
        \l__mymodule_acts_seq
        \__mymodule_map:nn
    \c__mymodule_fallthrough_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \TestFunction{key2}

    \TestFunction{key4}
\end{document}
```

This is much cleaner if you're able to use a single property list/key–val expression instead of a pair of clists:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Starting property list
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_prop {
    key1 = act1,
    key2 = act2,
    key3 = act3
}

% The user-accessible function
\NewDocumentCommand { \TestFunction } { m } {
    \prop_get:NnNTF \l__mymodule_keys_prop { #1 } \l_tmpa_tl {
        \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
    } {
        No ~ action!
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \TestFunction{key2}

    \TestFunction{key4}
\end{document}
```

The output is identical with both methods:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although expl3's mapping-functions seem not to be designed for doing 'in place'-manipulation on lists of tokens, in the following I assume that the LaTeX-distribution in use is recent enough for `\clist_map_function:NN` to be available. (interface3.pdf of my TeX-distribution says about `\clist_map_function:NN`: `Updated: 2012-06-29`. This is about 11 years ago, so assuming availability of `\clist_map_function:NN` might be reasonable.)

---

The gist of all following code is applying `\clist_map_function:NN` for mapping comma-list-items to a function/macro which uses an argument-delimiter for placing items nested in braces behind that delimiter. Before the delimiter you find the comma-list item in braces and the tokens forming the next iteration of the mapping-function.

So after each mapping-iteration you have s. th. like

`\function{⟨item in this mapping-iteration⟩}⟨stuff for subsequent mapping-iterations⟩\DELIMITER{⟨item from last mapping-iteration⟩}{⟨item from last but one mapping-iteration⟩}..{⟨item from first mapping-iteration⟩}`.

And `\function` uses arguments `#1` and `#2\DELIMITER` and does:

`⟨stuff for subsequent mapping-iterations⟩\DELIMITER{⟨item in this mapping-iteration⟩}{⟨item from last mapping-iteration⟩}{⟨item from last but one mapping-iteration⟩}..{⟨item from first mapping-iteration⟩}`.

So by and by from `items,of,list,a` and `ITEMS,OF,LIST,B`, s.th. like
`\DELIMITER{⟨result gathered so far, initially empty⟩}{B}{LIST}{OF}{ITEMS}{},{a}{list}{of}{items}{},`
is formed.

This in turn can be merged by using a loop where `\DELIMITER` is defined with an argument-pattern `#1#2#3,#4#5,` →
`\DELIMITER{{#2}{#4}#1}#3,#5,` and which terminates when `{#3#5}` is an empty argument so that `{#2}{#4}#1` forms the result of merging.

---

Caveat 1:

`⟨stuff for subsequent mapping-iterations⟩` must not contain `\DELIMITER` unless nested in curly braces.
I didn't bother checking the implementation of `\clist_map_function:NN` for finding out if the case of `⟨stuff for subsequent mapping-iterations⟩` containing `\DELIMITER` outside a pair of curly braces is possible.

Caveat 2:

Applying the function which is mapped to the single comma-list-items  leads to accumulating things in the input stack. Therefore with (not that) large comma-lists you might get error-messages like
`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=...].`

---

In the code below `\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw` is used in place of `\DELIMITER` and `\mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw` is used in place of `\function`/is mapped to the comma-list's items.

---

If you wish the content of `\l__mymodule_keys_clist` and `\l__mymodule_acts_clist` to be hardcoded  into the definition of `\TestFunction` so that the behavior of `\TestFunction` is not affected by subsequent changes to `\l__mymodule_keys_clist` and/or `\l__mymodule_acts_clist`, you can probably do s. th. like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% \DefineTestFunction{<control word token denoting test function to define>}%
%                    {<additional xparse-argument-specifiers, denoting #2, #3 etc>
%                      % #1 is available in <action if #1 is not a key of the keys comma list> 
%                      % in any case and denotes the argument to test
%                    }%
%                    {<keys comma list>}%
%                    {<actions comma list>}%
%                    {<action if #1 is not a key of the keys comma list>}%
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn #1#2#3#4#5 { 
  \exp_args:Nno \use:n
  { \NewDocumentCommand { #1 } { m#2 } } {
    \exp:w \exp_args:Nno \use:n {\exp_end: \str_case:nnF {##1} }
    {%
      \exp:w
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw{{},}
      \clist_map_function:NN #4 \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw{{},}
      \clist_map_function:NN #3 \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw{}
      \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw
    }{#5}
  }
}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw #1#2\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw 
  {#2 \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw #1}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw #1#2\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw 
  {#2 \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw {#1}}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw #1#2#3,#4#5,
  {\tl_if_empty:nTF{#3#5}{\exp_end:{#2}{#4}#1}{\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw {{#2}{#4}#1}#3,#5,}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_clist { key1, key2, key3 }
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_acts_clist { act1, act2, act3 }

\mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn{\TestFunction}{}
                                  {\l__mymodule_keys_clist}
                                  {\l__mymodule_acts_clist}
                                  {The~key~#1~is~not~in~the~list,~thus~default~action!}

\mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn{\OtherTestFunction}{m}
                                  {\l__mymodule_keys_clist}
                                  {\l__mymodule_acts_clist}
                                  {The~key~#1~is~not~in~the~list,~thus:~#2}

\cs_show:c{TestFunction~code}
\cs_show:c{OtherTestFunction~code}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TestFunction{key1}

\TestFunction{key2}

\TestFunction{key3}

\TestFunction{key4}

\OtherTestFunction{key1}{This time's default}

\OtherTestFunction{key2}{This time's default}

\OtherTestFunction{key3}{This time's default}

\OtherTestFunction{key4}{This time's default}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you wish the lists `\l__mymodule_keys_clist` and `\l__mymodule_acts_clist` to be evaluated at the time when `\TestFunction` is carried out, you can probably do s. th. like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% \DefineTestFunction{<control word token denoting test function to define>}%
%                    {<additional xparse-argument-specifiers, denoting #2, #3 etc>
%                      % #1 is available in <action if #1 is not a key of the keys comma list> 
%                      % in any case and denotes the argument to test
%                    }%
%                    {<keys comma list>}%
%                    {<actions comma list>}%
%                    {<action if #1 is not a key of the keys comma list>}%
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn #1#2#3#4#5 { 
  \NewDocumentCommand { #1 } { m#2 } {
    \exp_args:Nno \str_case:nnF {##1} 
    {%
      \exp:w
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw{{},}
      \clist_map_function:NN #4 \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw{{},}
      \clist_map_function:NN #3 \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw{}
      \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw
    }{#5}
  }
}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw #1#2\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw 
  {#2 \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw #1}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw #1#2\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw 
  {#2 \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw {#1}}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw #1#2#3,#4#5,
  {\tl_if_empty:nTF{#3#5}{\exp_end:{#2}{#4}#1}{\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw {{#2}{#4}#1}#3,#5,}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn{\TestFunction}{}
                                  {\l__mymodule_keys_clist}
                                  {\l__mymodule_acts_clist}
                                  {The~key~#1~is~not~in~the~list,~thus~default~action!}

\mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn{\OtherTestFunction}{m}
                                  {\l__mymodule_keys_clist}
                                  {\l__mymodule_acts_clist}
                                  {The~key~#1~is~not~in~the~list,~thus:~#2}

\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_clist { key1, key2, key3 }
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_acts_clist { act1, act2, act3 }

\cs_show:c{TestFunction~code}
\cs_show:c{OtherTestFunction~code}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TestFunction{key1}

\TestFunction{key2}

\TestFunction{key3}

\TestFunction{key4}

\OtherTestFunction{key1}{This time's default}

\OtherTestFunction{key2}{This time's default}

\OtherTestFunction{key3}{This time's default}

\OtherTestFunction{key4}{This time's default}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you wish to specify at the time when `\TestFunction` is carried out, which comma-list-variables to evaluate, you can probably do s. th. like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% \DefineTestFunction{<control word token denoting test function to define>}%
%                    {<additional xparse-argument-specifiers, denoting #4, #5 etc>
%                      % #1 is available in <action if #1 is not a key of the keys comma list> 
%                      % in any case and denotes the argument to test.
%                      % #2 is available in <action if #1 is not a key of the keys comma list> 
%                      % in any case and denotes the <keys comma list>.
%                      % #3 is available in <action if #1 is not a key of the keys comma list> 
%                      % in any case and denotes the <actions comma list>.
%                    }%
%                    {<action if #1 is not a key of the keys comma list>}%
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn #1#2#3 { 
  \NewDocumentCommand { #1 } { mmm#2 } {
    \exp_args:Nno \str_case:nnF {##1} 
    {%
      \exp:w
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw{{},}
      \clist_map_function:NN ##3 \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw{{},}
      \clist_map_function:NN ##2 \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw
      \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw{}
      \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw
    }{#3}
  }
}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsunbraced:nw #1#2\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw 
  {#2 \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw #1}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_moveargbehindmergecommalistsbraced:nw #1#2\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw 
  {#2 \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw {#1}}
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw #1#2#3,#4#5,
  {\tl_if_empty:nTF{#3#5}{\exp_end:{#2}{#4}#1}{\mymodule_mergecommalists:nnwnw {{#2}{#4}#1}#3,#5,}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn{\TestFunction}{}
                                  {The~key~#1~is~not~in~the~list,~thus~default~action!}

\mymodule_DefineTestFunction:NnNNn{\OtherTestFunction}{m}
                                  {The~key~#1~is~not~in~the~list,~thus:~#4}

\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_keys_clist { key1, key2, key3 }
\clist_set:Nn \l__mymodule_acts_clist { act1, act2, act3 }

\cs_show:c{TestFunction~code}
\cs_show:c{OtherTestFunction~code}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\TestFunction{key1}{\l__mymodule_keys_clist}{\l__mymodule_acts_clist}\par

\TestFunction{key2}{\l__mymodule_keys_clist}{\l__mymodule_acts_clist}\par

\TestFunction{key3}{\l__mymodule_keys_clist}{\l__mymodule_acts_clist}\par

\TestFunction{key4}{\l__mymodule_keys_clist}{\l__mymodule_acts_clist}\par

\OtherTestFunction{key1}{\l__mymodule_keys_clist}{\l__mymodule_acts_clist}{This~time's~default}\par

\OtherTestFunction{key2}{\l__mymodule_keys_clist}{\l__mymodule_acts_clist}{This~time's~default}\par

\OtherTestFunction{key3}{\l__mymodule_keys_clist}{\l__mymodule_acts_clist}{This~time's~default}\par

\OtherTestFunction{key4}{\l__mymodule_keys_clist}{\l__mymodule_acts_clist}{This~time's~default}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147423/discussion-on-answer-by-ulrich-diez-use-two-comma-lists-to-build-a-test-function); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.